# UIView Animation is far from smooth

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation

I am trying to scale a button up and down to call attention to it.

I have tried two animation methods:

**method 1**

```
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
animation.autoreverses = YES;
animation.repeatDuration = 2;
animation.duration = 0.4;
animation.fromValue = @(1.0f);
animation.toValue= @(1.2f);
[button.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"scale"];
```

**method 2**

```
  CGAffineTransform scaleUp = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.2f, 1.2f);
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse
                   animations:^{

                     [button setTransform:scaleUp];

                   } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                   }];
```

Same problem with both animations. Near the end, when the button is scaling down to its normal scale, the animation jumps directly to scale 1.0.

Something like:

1.2 ... 1.18 ... 1.15 ... boom ... 1.0

and I see the button popping from one huge scale value to 1, instead of being smooth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the final state of the button.In your case,the scale change like

1.0->1.1->1.2->1.1->1.0 **->1.2**(jump to final state)

Gif

[image]

```
CGAffineTransform scaleUp = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5f, 1.5f);
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse
                 animations:^{

                     [self.button setTransform:scaleUp];

                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     self.button.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
                 }];
```

Comment: perfect, but why? This defies logic. If the button scale is 1 and it scales up to 1.2 and I make the animation autoreverse, the logic says it will be back to 1.0. This is a total nonsense, but works. THANKS!!!

Comment: The animation will autoreverse,but not the final state.Core animation will decide with the code in `animations` block.In your case,the scale is 1.2.